# JSON.stringify fails on a newly created object (node, javascript)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, stringify

Ok, this one has to be a very easy question, but I just started learning node. I am also new to javascript, so, please show no mercy on pointing out wrong directions below.

In particular I have two files:

- one has a class that creates some slave servers in different ports
- the other one is the "main" file that generates the slaves

When I attempt to print out what I have just initialized I get two weird errors:

- connections property is deprecated. Use getConnections() method, and then
- it crashes when I attempt to apply JSON.stringify in the new object (Converting circular structure to JSON)

Code for slaves in file "slave.js":

```
var http = require ("http");

function Slave () {
}

Slave.prototype.ID           = undefined;
Slave.prototype.coordinator  = false;
Slave.prototype.httpServer   = undefined;
Slave.prototype.thePort      = undefined;

Slave.prototype.isCoordinator = function () { return this.coordinator; }

/*****************************************************************/

function handle_incoming_request (req, res) {
    console.log("INCOMING REQUEST: " + req.method + " " + req.url);
    res.writeHead (200, { "Content-Type" : "application/json" });
    res.end( JSON.stringify({ "error" : null }) + "\n" );
}

exports.createSlave = function (id, coordinatorK, port) {
    var temp         = new Slave ();
    temp.ID          = id;
    temp.coordinator = coordinatorK;
    temp.thePort     = port;
    temp.httpServer  = http.createServer(handle_incoming_request);
    temp.httpServer.listen (temp.thePort);
    console.log ("Slave (" + (temp.isCoordinator() ? "coordinator" : "regular") + ") with ID " + temp.ID + " is listening to port " + temp.thePort);
    console.log ("--------------------------------------------");

    return temp;
}
```

Now, the main file.

```
var http   = require ("http");
var url    = require ("url");
var a      = require ("./slave.js");

var i, temp;
var myArray = new Array ();

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var newID = i + 1;
    var newPort = 8000 + i + 1;
    var coordinatorIndicator = false;

    if ((i % 4) == 0) {
        coordinatorIndicator = true; // Say, this is going to be a coordinator
    }

    temp = a.createSlave (newID, coordinatorIndicator, newPort);
    console.log ("New slave is  : " + temp);
    console.log ("Stringified is: " + JSON.stringify(temp));

    myArray.push(temp);
}
```

Comment: You can't stringify just any old object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to stringify the result of `http.createServer(...)`. That'll not be what you want to do, so when you create that property, make it non-enumerable by defining it using `Object.defineProperty()`.

```
exports.createSlave = function (id, coordinatorK, port) {
    var temp         = new Slave ();
    temp.ID          = id;
    temp.coordinator = coordinatorK;
    temp.thePort     = port;

    Object.defineProperty(temp, "httpServer", {
        value: http.createServer(handle_incoming_request),
        enumerable: false, // this is actually the default, so you could remove it
        configurable: true,
        writeable: true
    });
    temp.httpServer.listen (temp.thePort);
    return temp;
}
```

This way `JSON.stringify` won't reach that property curing its enumeration of the object.

Comment: It is true that this one is working, with a minor change: the command temp.httpServer.listen (temp.thePort); should be after the Object.defineProperty(...). Please change this order.

I will wait for a few more minutes to see if there is another answer before I accept it. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Sure, I changed it. Didn't notice the order when I was editing.

Answer (score 2):

Issue is the with the property `httpServer` of `temp` object having circular reference. You can either set it non enumerable using `Ecmascript5` property definision as mentioned in the previous answer or you can use the replacer function of [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to customize it not to stringify the `httpServer` property.

```
   console.log ("Stringified is: " + JSON.stringify(temp, function(key, value){
         if(key === 'httpServer') return undefined;
        return value;
    }));
```

Comment: Thank you PSL for your time and the alternate explanation. I appreciate it. I am granting this one on user2736012 because he is lower on reputation though.

Comment: @MightyMouse You are welcome.. Ideally in node world you should go with EcmaScript5 definitions which will make it more standard way of defining objects. Since it was already posted i just provided an alternate.. You chose the right answer.. :)